# Should I seed and normalize a JSON dataset into my relational database or use another method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, database, activerecord

I'm in the process of making health and fitness web-app, for the sake of experimentation and my own learning.

The app uses Rails as a JSON API back-end, which interfaces with some front-end.

I currently have a `User` model, and a `Workout` model. I'm in the process of creating an `Exercise` model. I want my app to have a directory of 'exercises', and I want to use Active Record to associate a 'workout' as having many 'exercises', but I'm unsure of the best way to proceed from here.

I have a large dataset of exercises formatted in JSON. Here is the structure of a single exercise, for example:

```js
{
    "id": "0021",
    "name": "flat-bench-leg-raises",
    "title": "Flat Bench Leg Raises",
    "primer": "This is an exercise for lower abdominal strengthening.",
    "type": "isolation",
    "primary": [
        "abdominals"
    ],
    "secondary": [],
    "equipment": [
        "body"
    ],
    "steps": [
        "Lie on a flat bench with your hands under your hips supporting your back.",
        "Your legs should be unsupported by the bench from below your knees.",
        "With your feet together and your toes flexed upwards, raise your straight legs up a few cm off the bench; both of your legs should have no contact with the bench. This is your starting position.",
        "Keep your legs straight with a slight bend in the knees and raise your legs to just before 90 degrees with your hips.",
        "Pause at the top and lower your legs in slow controlled manner back to the starting position.",
        "Repeat."
    ],
    "tips": [
        "If you are pregnant you should contact your doctor prior to doing this exercise.",
        "Ensure your back stays in contact with the bench at all times during this exercise."
    ],
    "references": []
}
```

One idea I had was to create some logic within `db/seed.rb` that would iterate through each 'exercise' object, and save these exercises within the database.

But I'm not sure if this is the best course of action.

I find that when normalizing this data, I would end up with a data model that is less than elegant, and would have to add several additional models and relationships.

With this back-end being a JSON API, I would just end up sending this data back to the client in JSON format anyway.

Is this the right course of action or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right path. Recently I was trying to find a solution to my problem and used has_and_belongs_to_many relation. There was accounts and transactions in my case. And a transaction can has two account one is receiving and one is sending. account has_many transactions. In your case workout has_many exercise and exercise can belong to many workout programs.

In order to use this kind of relation you can read this links.

[apidock.com](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many)
[RailsGuide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

And also there is [negative reviews](https://flatironschool.com/blog/why-you-dont-need-has-and-belongs-to-many) about this approach

`db/seed.rb` is a good way of populate data on database. If your exercises are on your local machine you can use [seed dump gem](https://github.com/rroblak/seed_dump) to create seed files really quick.